# how does the linux shell in a multi-processor computer read the keyboard inputs?

Tags: linux, shell, irq

After reading [this document](http://www.computer-engineering.org/index.html), I know that the keyboard input will activate **irq 1** pointed to some interrupt. Then our processors will  decode the input and do something else.

`My question` is how a shell knows the keyboard input if the other processor handles the interrupt?

### For example:

processor A is running shell

processor B handles the interrupt.

Comment: so? it's still just one kernel running the whole show, so processor B handles the kernel's "process keyboard input" stuff, the input goes into a queue somewhere, and the kernel will figure out what process has focus and should be notified that there's input available.

Comment: The keyboard is read by the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interrupt handler will either directly add the key press to a queue, or trigger a pop-up thread to do so. The queue is in shared memory, so can be read by any CPU.